# Default worker process does not start in docker without debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, containers

Maybe it is something obvious, but cannot figure it out.

I have just out-of-the-box C# Worker service solution in Visual Studio (2022, .NET 6). Docker support is on. When I press 'Debug' - it starts docker container and runs app. Everything looks fine on the console (by default it just write messages each 1 sec.)

Now if I leave VS and just open up CMD and type:

```
docker ps
```

I would see the image created during Visual Studio runtime. If I try to start it by:

```
docker run workerservicedocker:dev
```

I get quick output like:

[image]

So no code execution actually happens. Looks like app is getting opened/closed immediately. I'm just trying Docker approach, so maybe I'm missing something obvious. As I mentioned it is just default template solution, no modifications from my side.
Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WorkerServiceDocker/WorkerServiceDocker.csproj", "WorkerServiceDocker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WorkerServiceDocker/WorkerServiceDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WorkerServiceDocker"
RUN dotnet build "WorkerServiceDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WorkerServiceDocker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WorkerServiceDocker.dll"]
```

This is default Dockerfile created by VS.

**UPDATE:**

If I do

```
docker run -it  workerservicedocker:dev
```

like it was suggested in the reply below - it just shows app> commandline, but no actual execution happens.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile?

Comment: Just added it's content

Comment: One thing that strikes me as odd is that you create a Linux image (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0` is Linux), but when you run it, it displays the "Microsoft Windows ..." text like it's a Windows image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run -it workerservicedocker:dev`
attaches stdin and a psuedo-tty

basically, the way you run it, it's in the "background".
If you `docker ps` you'll see your container running.
Grab the container id, `docker logs <id>` and you'll see your output.

With `-it` it effectively attaches the container to your console.
When you run from VS it does this for you.

---

additional:
The actual problem is that VS is being "clever"
The ":dev" tag is just the base stage (basically nothing). VS then squirts in the code and builds. It does this for edit-continue, debugging etc.
(check the output/container-tools window. See the "--target base" arg)

Right click the Dockerfile and select "Build Docker Image". This actually runs the entire dockerfile and gives you a ":latest" tag which will contain what you expected.

`docker run -it workerservicedocker:latest`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it, but it just navigates me to the console which does not execute default implementation of the default project. I have updated initial post to include this.

Comment: I think my updated answer explains it. Basically it's VS not doing what you think/expect it to do. --- for production work, I never use the VS created Dockerfile. It's far too convoluted and brittle when you have a load of project dependencies

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works out. Looks that I was not completely clear about building projects of that type :)